# No HDMI sound output on Thinkpad X1

Tags: 11.10, sound, hdmi, thinkpad

I'm having problems getting my sound to output via HDMI to my TV.

When I go to Sound Settings, the HDMI device does not appear.

```
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I don't know if the video information is helpful, but anyway:

```
~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: @BlueXrider yeah, still no luck here.

Comment: removed closing flag

Comment: Type `pacmd` in console and please post the output of `list-sinks`. To exit the pacmd console, press `Ctrl+C` (typing exit terminates the pulseaudio daemon).

Comment: @jeremija https://gist.github.com/3508685

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you might need to alter your default pulseaudio configuration. Backup the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file and the edit it. Look for the part where it says

```
### Automatically load driver modules edepending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect.so
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev/nal support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

and change it to (try with hw:0,3 to hw:0,7 or hw:0,8 if neccessary - this is based on your `aplay -l` output):

```
### Automatically load driver modules edepending on the hardware available
#.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
#load-module module-udev-detect.so
#.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev/nal support)
#load-module module-detect
#.endif

load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi
```

Then restart the pulseaudio server. If it's running on per-user basis, type `pulseaudio --kill` and then `pulseaudio --start`. If it's running as a system service type `sudo service pulseaudio restart`. To check that, run `ps -ef | grep pulse` and see what user (left column) started the pulseaudio application: if it's root, than it's a system service, if it's your user, than use the kill and start method. While experimenting with the configuration files, you can run it with `pulseaudio -vvv` to see debug information.

Note that this configuration is only to see if you can get the hdmi output to work. After you have found out which hw:0,# to use, for example if your hdmi output works with `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,7 sink_name=hdmi`, try uncommenting the loading of module-udev-detect/module-detect modules so that the pulseaudio can detect whatever it detects now, you should end up with something like this:

```
### Automatically load driver modules edepending on the hardware available
#.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect.so
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev/nal support)
load-module module-detect
#.endif

load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,7 sink_name=hdmi
```

I suggest that you use `pavucontrol` for choosing/viewing the output devices for pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

Here on an X1 (2017), I can switch between HDMI and analog audio output with the command

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

and I can switch back using

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

I've found those commands in the arch wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Automatically_switch_audio_to_HDMI